# How does std::declval return a value?

Tags: c++

I wanted to try writing a template wrapper that checks whether a class has a member function.
and for this it was necessary to use std::declval

```
template<typename T>
struct has_member<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back())>>:std::true_type{};
```

As I saw, the implementation of declval should be like this:

```
template<typename T>
T&& declval() noexcept;
```

And actually, it may be a odd question ,but why does declval have no return statement ?

If I understand correctly, it should return rvalue to the place of its call:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_member<T, void_t<decltype(T&&.push_back())>>:std::true_type{};
```

But we don't use return in the implementation . Maybe it's because we don't have a function body?I would like to understand why this is possible. I would be happy to help

Comment: `std::declval` should only be used in unevaluated contexts. It would be an error to try to actually do anything with its return value. It will never actually be called, so it doesn't need an implementation.

Comment: `but why does declval have no return statement ?` because `Maybe it's because we don't have a function body?`. Its not implemented, only declared. What we care about is the type, not the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`declval` has no `return` statement because the function has no implementation. If you ever tried to call `declval`, you would get a compile error.

`declval` exists to be used in what C++ calls an "unevaluated context". This is in a place where an expression will be parsed, the types used worked out, but the expression will never actually be evaluated. The expression given to `decltype` is an unevaluated context.

Even though `declval` has no implementation, it is a function with a well-defined return type. So even though you can't actually execute it, the compiler does know what the type of `declval<T>()` will be. And therefore, the compiler can examine the expression containing it.

See, `T&&` is a type; you cannot use `.` on a type. The result of calling a function is an object (or `void`), which *has a type*, but *isn't* itself a type. What you want to say is "assuming I have a value of type `T`, I want to do X to it". You can't say that with `T&&` because it's a type, not an object. And you don't want to limit `T` to things which are default constructible, so you can't just say `T{}`.

That's where `declval` comes in.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.Do I understand correctly that ```T &&``` meaning an rvalue object that is not instantiated (for incomplete type) and decltype is applied to it?

Comment: @MarekR: Some implementations do actually fail the compile.

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

> Note that declval can only be used in unevaluated contexts and is not required to be defined; it is an error to evaluate an expression that contains this function. Formally, the program is ill-formed if this function is odr-used.

The usage in your code can be simplified to

```
using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back());
```

And [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> Inspects the declared type of an entity or the type and value category of an expression.

`std::declval` is never called, so it needs no definition. The declaration is enough for the compiler to deduce its return type.

In other words...

> But we don't use return in the implementation

`declval` has no implementation.

Comment: @Bathsheba I just ended my working day and finding questions I can learn from keep me from going out into the sun. But enough for today.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for the answer!